# What's the normal temperature of a AAO751h?

Tags: acer, aspire-one

What should be the normal temperature be for an Acer Aspire One 751h with a 9 cells battery running Kubuntu 10.10?
The plasmoid indicates temperatures from 53º C up to 63º C (isn't this too high?)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that is CPU temperature. That seems in line with other processors of its type. 75ºC should be the upper limit to what you ever see.

If it's getting above 80ºC for extended periods, you might have a problem. Above 100-110ºC and you need to turn it off and get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

- On my Vostro 1520 laptop, it is 28ºC when I start, 40ºC  when I use normally the machine, 55ºC  when I watch videos. It is annoying because the fan triggers around 48ºC and stops arounds 40ºC .
- If I use a second procedure: "sudo modprobe i8k force=1" and "i8kctl", a different temperature is displayed, something like  60ºC. Note that this procedure implies my system to freeze. It comes back fine after reboot.

The CPU is:
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GHz